# stream is not returning updated post, even though post has an updated_time timestamp

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Weird stuff going on here:

```
fql?q=SELECT post_id, updated_time, created_time, message 
FROM stream WHERE source_id = 8576093908 AND updated_time > 1330761040 
-> no data
```

but:

```
fql?q=SELECT post_id, updated_time, created_time, message 
from stream where post_id = '8576093908_10150645788623909'
-> {
  "data": [
    {
      "post_id": "8576093908_10150645788623909",
      "updated_time": 1330761042,
      "created_time": 1330624006,
      "message": "...."
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the actual post says: Yup, I was updated 1330761042
But when you want to see the post using the stream, it won't work -> no data

Anybody has an idea?